# How can I show that an analytic function can be bounded from below as follows?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, power-series, analytic-functions

I have the following problem:

> Let $f$ be a nonzero analytic function on $B:=\{|z|<1\}$. Show that there exists $c>0$, $r>0$ and $k=0,1,2,...$ such that $$|f(z)|\geq c|z|^k$$when $|z|<r$.

My idea was the following:

Since $f$ is analytic on $B$ and $0\in B$ we know that $f$ is analytic at $0$. By definition $\exists r>0$ such that on $|z-0|=|z|<r$ $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-0)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z ^n$$Therefore $$|f(z)|=\left|\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n\right|$$

I see now some similarities to $c|z|^k$. But I'm somehow thinking about how one could find this $c$.

Does someone have a hint how I can proceed?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(0)\ne0$, take $\delta>0$ such that\begin{align}|z|<\delta&\implies|f(z)-f(0)|<\frac12|f(0)|\\&\implies|f(z)|>\frac12|f(0)|.\end{align}Now, let $r=\delta$, $k=0$, and $c=\frac12|f(0)|$.

And if $f(0)=0$, let $k$ be the order of $0$ as a zero of $f$. So, near $0$ you have$$f(z)=a_kz^k+a_{k+1}z^{k+1}+\cdots,$$with $a_k\ne0$. So, if $z\ne0$,$$\frac{f(z)}{z^k}=a_k+a_{k+1}z+\cdots$$and you can apply the same argument as above to this function; it follows that there are $c>0$ and $r\in(0,1)$ such that, when $|z|\in(0,r)$,$$\left|\frac{f(z)}{z^k}\right|>c\left(\iff|f(z)|>c|z|^k\right).$$

Comment: so but my inequality $|f|\geq c|z|^k$ goes in the other direction. Does it then still works?

Comment: It was a typo. I meant to write $>$.

Comment: and is this really a strict inequality?

Comment: Yes, unless $z=0$, of course.

Comment: but why do we consider $f(0)=0$ I mean the function is nonzero

Comment: The function being nonzero means that we don't have $f(z)=0$ for *every* $z$. But the function can have some zeros.

Comment: It seems to me that you are not interested in my answer. Do you delete it?

Comment: No your answer is rally good and I will upvote and accept it if I understood everything but at the moment I'm still trying to understand why this proof works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134461/discussion-between-wave-and-jose-carlos-santos).

Would it be possible to discuss shortly my questions?

Comment: I asked again two questions in the chat, where I'm not really convinced at the moment. I'm sorry...